# How to replace existing command from default catalog in Magnolia CMS

Tags: content-management-system, magnolia

I need to replace existing command 'publish' from catalog 'default' with my own implementation. I created my own module and added command 'publish' in catalog 'default' like in the picture below:

[image]

Unfortunately this doesn't override existing command but if I change the name to `publish1` it appears in catalog 'default'. Is it possible to override existing command? I yes, how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Commands have a class property that you can change directly in the default implementation. If you need to change that property programmatically, you can use version handler tasks e.g. `info.magnolia.module.delta.CheckAndModifyPropertyValueTask` should do it for you.